# Counting permutations with two urns

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose two urns, with $n$ numbered balls in each. How many permutations, out of the $(2n)!$ possible, exchange $m$ balls between the urns?

My reasoning was as follows: There are ${n\choose m}^2$ ways to choose which balls will be exchanged. There are $m!$ permutations among the balls that will be exchanged, and $(n-m)!^2$ permutations among the balls that will remain in each urn. So the solution should be $P_{n,m}={n\choose m}^2m!(n-m)!^2$.

However, this formula gives $P_{3,0}=36$ and $P_{3,1}=36$, while I am told that the correct results should be  $P_{3,0}=36$ and $P_{3,1}=324$.

Comment: As an aside, you should clarify that order *within* the urns apparently matters.  In these quintessential combinatorics problems you find in every book, it is far more common for "urns" to be such that order within them does not matter.  A better analogy here might have been two $n$-person classrooms with assigned seating exchanging $m$ students (*and reassigning seats*), for example as they move up a grade from freshman to sophomore year or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is $$\binom{n}{m}^2(n!)^2$$  Once we have chosen the balls to be exchanged, we have two collections of $n$ balls.  Each of these may be arranged in $n!$ ways.  Your have assumed that the balls moved from one urn to the other, will occupy the same spots as the balls removed from the destination urn, but that isn't necessarily so.